# Trigonometry why coefficient of $x$ must be $1$ before phase shift

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Why in $\sin(bx+c)$ the phase shift isn't just $c$, because we are shifting each value of $bx$ by $c$ to the left, why is it $c/b$, I just cant leave it without fully understanding, please help me.

Comment: What is phase shift?

Comment: It is just about how you get from $\sin(x)$ to $\sin(bx+c)$ using changes of variable $x\to rx$ and $x\to x+s$. The first change of variable is a change in frequency, and the second a phase shift. If you start with $\sin(x)$ and change variable to $x\to bx$, then you get $\sin(bx)$. In order to get from this to $\sin(bx+c)$, then you would need to change variable with $x\to x+c/b$ to get $\sin(b(x+c/b))=\sin(bx+c)$. You say, then that $\sin(bx+c)$ has a phase shift of $c/b$ from $\sin(bx)$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: That would be more suitable as an answer than as a comment.

Comment: Reread your own comment, and try unpacking it. "shifting each value of $bx$ by $c$ "